# Expand only the selected row in a nested table

Tags: html, jquery, css

I am trying to expand a nested row in a table by clicking an icon. Initially, I was expanding on click of the row as below.

```
$(function(){
    $(".fold-table tr.view").on("click", function(){
      $(this).toggleClass("open").next(".fold").toggleClass("open");
    });
  });
```

It was working fine. Now when I want to expand on click I don't know what to replace the 'this' keyword with so the it only expands the selected row and not the entire table at once.

```
$(function(){
  $(".expand").on("click", function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("open").next(".fold").toggleClass("open");
  });
})
```

```
<body>

    <table class="table fold-table parent" id="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>

                <th scope="col">Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Designation</th>
                <th scope="col">Contact Details</th>
                <th scope="col">Email</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="view">

                <td col="Name">John</td>
                <td col="Designation">j@g.com</td>
                <td col="Contact Details">
                    <span class="contactInfo">
                        <img class="contact mr-2" src="./assets/call.png" />35373726<br>
                        <img class="contact mr-2" src="./assets/call.png" />35373726
                    </span>
                </td>
                <td col="Email">John@g.com<img class="expand ml-2" src="arrow.png" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="fold">
                <td colspan="4">
                    <div class="fold-content">

                        <table class="child">

                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td col="Name">SUB Category 1</td>
                                    <td col="Designation">SUB Category 2</td>
                                    <td col="Contact Details">SUB Category 3</td>
                                    <td col="Email">John@g.com
                                    
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>

                                    <td col="Name">SUB Category 1</td>
                                    <td col="Designation">SUB Category 2</td>
                                    <td col="Contact Details">SUB Category 3</td>
                                    <td col="Email">John@g.com
                                    
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td col="Name">SUB Category 1</td>
                                    <td col="Designation">SUB Category 2</td>
                                    <td col="Contact Details">SUB Category 3</td>
                                    <td col="Email">John@g.com
                                        
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>

        <tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```

```
.expand {
  cursor: pointer;
}

 table.fold-table > tbody > tr.fold {
  display: none;
}

table.fold-table > tbody > tr.fold.open {
  display: table-row;

}
```

For demonstration, I have only added one row in parent table and three in child table. How can I get this expand thing to work ?

Your help will be appreciated.

Thanks :)

Comment: Can you add another row or 2 into the example so we can see how it is structured, so that we know how to select the correct row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) function to get `tr` and then go to `next()` class which is `.fold` to `toggleClass('open')`

**Working Demo:**

```js
$(function(){
  $(".expand").on("click", function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("open").closest('tr').next('.fold').toggleClass("open");
  });
})
```

```css
.expand {
  cursor: pointer;
}

 table.fold-table > tbody > tr.fold {
  display: none;
}

table.fold-table > tbody > tr.fold.open {
  display: table-row;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

  <table class="table fold-table parent" id="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>

        <th scope="col">Name</th>
        <th scope="col">Designation</th>
        <th scope="col">Contact Details</th>
        <th scope="col">Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="view">

        <td col="Name">John</td>
        <td col="Designation">j@g.com</td>
        <td col="Contact Details">
          <span class="contactInfo">
            <img class="contact mr-2" src="./assets/call.png" />35373726<br>
            <img class="contact mr-2" src="./assets/call.png" />35373726
          </span>
        </td>
        <td col="Email">John@g.com<img class="expand ml-2" src="arrow.png" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="fold">
        <td colspan="4">
          <div class="fold-content">
            <table class="child">

              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td col="Name">SUB Category 1</td>
                  <td col="Designation">SUB Category 2</td>
                  <td col="Contact Details">SUB Category 3</td>
                  <td col="Email">John@g.com

                  </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>

                  <td col="Name">SUB Category 1</td>
                  <td col="Designation">SUB Category 2</td>
                  <td col="Contact Details">SUB Category 3</td>
                  <td col="Email">John@g.com

                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td col="Name">SUB Category 1</td>
                  <td col="Designation">SUB Category 2</td>
                  <td col="Contact Details">SUB Category 3</td>
                  <td col="Email">John@g.com
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>

    <tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

In vanilla Javascript you can use the following answer: (for the jQuery OP please refer to @AlwaysHelping post)

I would keep the original code, adding the previous expand as a global/class variable to close it before opening the next on:

```
 document.querySelectorAll('tbody.toggle').forEach(e => (e.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    const current = [e.currentTarget.querySelector('.view'), e.currentTarget.querySelector('.fold')];
    if (window.previous && window.previous[0] !== current[0]) {
      window.previous[0].classList.remove('open');
      window.previous[1].classList.remove('open');
    }

    current[0].classList.toggle('open');
    current[1].classList.toggle('open');
    window.previous = current;
  })));
```

If you decide to use clases change the `window` into the correct `this._property`

See the following snippet:

```html
<style>
  .fold {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  .fold.open {
    visibility: visible;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <table class="table fold-table parent" id="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Name</th>
        <th scope="col">Designation</th>
        <th scope="col">Contact Details</th>
        <th scope="col">Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="toggle">
      <tr class="view">
        <td col="Name">John</td>
        <td col="Designation">j@g.com</td>
        <td col="Contact Details">
          <span class="contactInfo">
            <img class="contact mr-2" src="./assets/call.png" />35373726<br />
            <img class="contact mr-2" src="./assets/call.png" />35373726
          </span>
        </td>
        <td col="Email">John@g.com<img class="expand ml-2" src="arrow.png" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="fold">
        <td colspan="4">
          <div class="fold-content">
            <table class="child">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td col="Name">SUB Category 1</td>
                  <td col="Designation">SUB Category 2</td>
                  <td col="Contact Details">SUB Category 3</td>
                  <td col="Email">John@g.com</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td col="Name">SUB Category 1</td>
                  <td col="Designation">SUB Category 2</td>
                  <td col="Contact Details">SUB Category 3</td>
                  <td col="Email">John@g.com</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td col="Name">SUB Category 1</td>
                  <td col="Designation">SUB Category 2</td>
                  <td col="Contact Details">SUB Category 3</td>
                  <td col="Email">John@g.com</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody class="toggle">
      <tr class="view">
        <td col="Name">John 2</td>
        <td col="Designation">j@g.com</td>
        <td col="Contact Details">
          <span class="contactInfo">
            <img class="contact mr-2" src="./assets/call.png" />35373726<br />
            <img class="contact mr-2" src="./assets/call.png" />35373726
          </span>
        </td>
        <td col="Email">John@g.com<img class="expand ml-2" src="arrow.png" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="fold">
        <td colspan="4">
          <div class="fold-content">
            <table class="child">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td col="Name">SUB Category 1</td>
                  <td col="Designation">SUB Category 2</td>
                  <td col="Contact Details">SUB Category 3</td>
                  <td col="Email">John@g.com</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td col="Name">SUB Category 1</td>
                  <td col="Designation">SUB Category 2</td>
                  <td col="Contact Details">SUB Category 3</td>
                  <td col="Email">John@g.com</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td col="Name">SUB Category 1</td>
                  <td col="Designation">SUB Category 2</td>
                  <td col="Contact Details">SUB Category 3</td>
                  <td col="Email">John@g.com</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

<script>
  document.querySelectorAll('tbody.toggle').forEach(e => (e.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    const current = [e.currentTarget.querySelector('.view'), e.currentTarget.querySelector('.fold')];
    if (window.previous && window.previous[0] !== current[0]) {
      window.previous[0].classList.remove('open');
      window.previous[1].classList.remove('open');
    }

    current[0].classList.toggle('open');
    current[1].classList.toggle('open');
    window.previous = current;
  })));
</script>
```

Comment: I didn't understand completely. Could you please explain ? Is the first approach suggested above not complete?

Comment: I've updated the post in hopes it's self-explanatory, if not just let me know

Comment: @aemonge Why would you suggest 15 other lines of codes in to do the same thing and make things complicated to get the same results. When a simple neat function `closest` can do that job. See my answer.

Comment: @aemonge use the `DRY` method which means `do not repeat yourself` when writing a code to meet the standard of coding.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping I'm aiming to help by only having one row "open", which is what I though was the issue. As you say it can be done more efficiently with the `.closest`, although I used to avoid lateral navigation in the DOM.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping I really don't understand where am I repeating my self, can you please explain this better for me ?

Comment: @aemonge You need to refer to the question which was asked. OP is using jQuery library to get the results. You are making a simple solution very complicated using native JavaScript. You are repeating the code by adding classes removing classes. Using for each loop, window methods etc etc.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping I've added into the post that this solution isn't the OP/jQuery one but useful only for vanilla/native JS.  About the loops, since its vanilla they're necessary, but the removal of the class happens only when you toggle-open another item in the list.

Comment: @aemonge No worries. Thanks for your effort though.